# ResultSet в SELECT c логикой не работает

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Вот такой код:

```
  private void Drop(int id_bots, int id_players) throws SQLException {
    int i = 0;
    Drop drop = new Drop();  //подключаю экземпляр класса ДРОП
    Queries queries = new Queries();  //поключаю экземпляр класса Запросы
    query = "SELECT d.chance, o.name, o.id_Objects, o.isStakan FROM drops d" +
            " LEFT JOIN bots b ON d.id_bots=b.id_bots" +
            " LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.id_Objects=d.id_Objects" +
            " WHERE b.id_bots =" + id_bots + ";"; //код SQL-запроса
    res = statement.executeQuery(query); //запускаю запрос
    //в цикле прохожу всю таблицу и пишу данные в сеттеры
    while (res.next()) {
        boolean j = false;
        drop.setChance(res.getDouble("chance"));
        drop.setName(res.getString("name"));
        drop.setId_Objects(res.getInt("id_Objects"));
        drop.setIsStakan(res.getInt("isStakan"));

        System.out.println(drop.toString());

        if (Math.random() <= drop.getChance()){  //если вещь выпала
            System.out.println("Выпала вещь - " + drop.getName());
            if (drop.getIsStakan() == 1) { //и она стаканется
                System.out.println(drop.getName() + " стаканется");
                //ищу такие вещи в рюкзаке перса
                query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS kol FROM inventory i WHERE i.id_players = " + id_players +
                        " AND i.id_Objects = " + drop.getId_Objects() + ";"; //код SQL-запроса
                ResultSet objectStakan = statement.executeQuery(query); //запускаю запрос
                while (objectStakan.next()) {
                    queries.setCount(objectStakan.getInt("kol"));
                    System.out.println("К-во предметов, которые стаканятся " + queries.getCount());
                }
                objectStakan.close(); //закрываю обьект
                if(queries.getCount() == 1) { //если такие вещи есть в инвентаре этого перса
                    System.out.println("в рюкзаке есть еще и другие " + drop.getName());
                    //добавляю еще одно кол-во
                    query = "UPDATE inventory SET kol = kol + 1 WHERE i.id_players = " + id_players +
                            " AND i.id_Objects = " + drop.getId_Objects() + ";"; //код SQL-запроса
                    statement.executeUpdate(query); //выполнение запроса
                    nameDropArray[i] = ", " + drop.getName();  //добавляю в масив название дропа
                } else { //если таких вещей нет в инвентаре этого перса
                    System.out.println("в рюкзаке нет других " + drop.getName());
                    j = true; //добавляю новую запись в таблицу inventory
                }
            } else { //если предмет не стаканется
                System.out.println(drop.getName() + " не стаканется");
                j = true; //добавляю новую запись в таблицу inventory
            }
        }
        if (j == true) {
            //проверяю, есть ли место в рюкзаке
            query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS kol FROM inventory i " +
                    "LEFT JOIN objects o ON i.id_Objects = o.id_Objects " +
                    "WHERE i.id_players = " + id_players +
                    " AND (o.isQuest IS NULL OR o.isQuest = '' OR o.isQuest = 0);"; //код SQL-запроса
            ResultSet inventory = statement.executeQuery(query); //запускаю запрос
            while (inventory.next()) {
                queries.setCount(inventory.getInt("kol"));
                System.out.println("К-во вещей в рюкзаке - " + queries.getCount());
            }
            inventory.close();  //закрываю обьект
            queries.setCount(1);
            if (queries.getCount() < players.getSize_inventory()) { //если есть место в инвентаре
                //добавляю новый предмет в инвентарь этого перса
                query = "INSERT INTO inventory (id_players, id_Objects, kol) " +
                        "VALUES (" + id_players + ", " + drop.getId_Objects() + ", 1);"; //код SQL-запроса
                statement.execute(query);  //выполняю запрос
                System.out.println("в рюкзае попал дроп - " + drop.getName());
                nameDropArray[i] = ", " + drop.getName();  //добавляю в масив название дропа
            } else {  //если нет места в инвентаре
                System.out.println("Рюкзак " + players.getName() + " переполнен");
                drop.setName("рюкзак переполнен");
                nameDropArray[i] = ", " + drop.getName();  //добавляю в масив название дропа
            }
        }
        System.out.println("222 в рюкзае попал дроп - " + nameDropArray[i]);
        System.out.println("Цикл для дропа прошел " + i + " раз");
        i++;  //инкремент
    }
    res.close(); //закрываю обьект
    drop = null;
    queries = null;
}
```

вот что я получаю в результате:

```
Drop{Шанс: 1.0, Название: Старые шорты, id_Objects: 1, Стаканется: 0}
Выпала вещь - Старые шорты
Старые шорты не стаканется
К-во вещей в рюкзаке - 5
в рюкзае попал дроп - Старые шорты
222 в рюкзае попал дроп - , Старые шорты
Цикл для дропа прошел 0 раз
Невозможно обработать SQL-запрос, ошибка № java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:768)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7008)
at ServeOneThread.Drop(Main.java:370)
```

строка на которую ругается Main.java:370 -

```
while (res.next()) {
```

Если без этой логики с дропом, то весь цикл  while (res.next()) {} проходит без ошибок. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все делаю так как и делал. Только "главный" ResultSet надо сделать отдельно, а потом запускать другие. Для этого:

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...; - узнаю к-во записей для моего "главного" запроса.
2. Делаю "главный" запрос, а ResultSet записываю в цикле, как ни банально, в массивы. Например:

   while (res.next()) {
      переменная[i] = res.getString(1);
      i++
   }
3. А дальше в цикле (где к-во равно результату с запроса п.1), как этому учат на всех сайтах и учебниках, вытягиваю данные с массивов и делаю все остальные запросы и ResultSet как я делал раньше.

P.S. Результат з п. 1 также нужен для инициализации массивов (указания их длины), т.е. их длина не будет больше к-ву строк в "главном" запросе.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы вызываете `statement.executeQuery(...)` внутри цикла, текущий `ResultSet` (`res`) автоматически закрывается - см. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html:

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement`
>   interface implicitly close a current `ResultSet` object of the statement
>   if an open one exists.

Поэтому на следующей итерации при вызове `res.next()` вы получаете соответствующий `SQLException`.

Answer (score -2):

Спасибо всем. То что новый ResultSet внутри цикла закрывает текущий я это и сам понял. Я хотел совета, как это обойти.
Решение я нашел. Все намного проще чем я думал. Если у кого будет похожая ситуация в алгоритме, пишите мне и я с радостью поделюсь советом.

Comment: Так поделитесь, раз ответ есть.